# Facing error java.io.IOException: Stream Closed while merging 2 pdfs

Tags: java, pdf

I was trying to merge two PDF documents that come from a JSP page via file upload. I am getting the files, putting them inside a list, but when I am trying to read them for merging, I am getting a "Stream Closed" message. I searched many responses on this exception, but none helped. So, putting it again, not sure where is it failing.

Below is the Java code:

```
public class MergePdfUtility {
FormDataBean formData = null;

public String mergePdf(String contentType, InputStream inputStream, int formDataLength,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    String saveFile = new String();
    String strUploadFile = "";
    File flUploadFile = null;
    formData = new FormDataBean();


    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString();
                if(fieldvalue == null || fieldvalue.length() == 0) {
                    fieldvalue = "Merger.pdf";
                }
                System.out.println("Field Value = " + fieldvalue);

                if (fieldname.equals("txtFileName")) {
                    formData.setStrFileName(fieldvalue);
                    System.out.println("successfully assigned");
                }
            } else {
                saveFile = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());                   
                if (saveFile.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    inputStream = item.getInputStream();
                    contentType = item.getContentType();
                    strUploadFile = "D:\\Samik\\BCP\\" + saveFile;
                    flUploadFile = new File(strUploadFile);
                    FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream(flUploadFile);
                    BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fileout);
                    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
                    int byte_;

                    while ((byte_ = bin.read()) != -1) {
                        bout.write(byte_);
                    }
                    list.add(inputStream);

                    bout.close();
                    bin.close();
                    fileout.flush();
                    fileout.close();                        
                }
            }
        }

        mergePdf(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();            
        return "failure";
    }       
    return "success";
}

private static void mergePdf(List<InputStream> list)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
    OutputStream mergeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Samik\\BCP\\" + "Merger.pdf"));
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, mergeOutputStream);
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
    for (InputStream tempInputStream : list) {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            document.newPage();
            PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
            pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    mergeOutputStream.close();
    document.close();
}

}
```

I am getting an exception at the line:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
```

The exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.InputStreamToArray(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:179)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray.<init>(RandomAccessFileOrArray.java:172)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:237)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:248)
at com.tcs.pdfutil.MergePdfUtility.mergePdf(MergePdfUtility.java:108)
at com.tcs.pdfutil.MergePdfUtility.mergePdf(MergePdfUtility.java:86)
at org.apache.jsp.MergePdfUtility_jsp._jspService(MergePdfUtility_jsp.java:83)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is the exact problem? Where is the inputStream being closed?

==============================================================================
Added 3rd July:

Thanks @Anonymity.This helped me solve the issue, but partially. I am now able to merge up to 5 pdf documents, and even delete the source documents after merging them - but I am still unable to get a success message. After doing everything perfectly, the control goes to IOException and I am getting the same error at last - `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`, which leads to returning a "failure" message. Not able to trace out where am I going wrong.

My code now looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MergePdfUtility {
FormDataBean formData = null;

public String mergePdf(String contentType, int formDataLength, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String saveFile = new String();
    String strUploadFile = "";
    File flUploadFile = null;
    formData = new FormDataBean();
    FileOutputStream fileout = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bout = null;
    BufferedInputStream bin = null;
    String strStatusMsg;
    InputStream inputStream1 = null;
    InputStream inputStream2 = null;
    InputStream inputStream3 = null;
    InputStream inputStream4 = null;
    InputStream inputStream5 = null;

    try {
        List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
        List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        //List<InputStream> finalList = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

        for (FileItem item : items) {
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                String fieldname = item.getFieldName();
                String fieldvalue = item.getString() + ".pdf";
                if (fieldvalue == null || fieldvalue.length() == 0 || fieldvalue.equals(".pdf")) {
                    fieldvalue = "Merger.pdf";
                }
                System.out.println("Field Value = " + fieldvalue);

                if (fieldname.equals("txtFileName")) {
                    formData.setStrFileName(fieldvalue);
                    System.out.println("successfully assigned");
                }
            } else {
                saveFile = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
                if (saveFile.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    String strFieldName = item.getFieldName();
                    System.out.println(saveFile);

                    contentType = item.getContentType();
                    strUploadFile = "D:\\Samik\\BCP\\" + saveFile;
                    flUploadFile = new File(strUploadFile);
                    fileout = new FileOutputStream(flUploadFile);
                    bin = new BufferedInputStream(item.getInputStream());
                    bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fileout);

                    int byte_;

                    while ((byte_ = bin.read()) != -1) {
                        bout.write(byte_);
                    }
                    bout.flush();
                    bout.close();
                    //bin.close();
                    if(strFieldName.endsWith("1")) {
                        inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(flUploadFile);
                        list.add(inputStream1);
                        formData.setFile1(flUploadFile);
                    } else if(strFieldName.endsWith("2")) {
                        inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(flUploadFile);
                        list.add(inputStream2);
                        formData.setFile2(flUploadFile);
                    }
                    else if(strFieldName.endsWith("3")) {
                        inputStream3 = new FileInputStream(flUploadFile);
                        list.add(inputStream3);
                        formData.setFile3(flUploadFile);
                    }
                    else if(strFieldName.endsWith("4")) {
                        inputStream4 = new FileInputStream(flUploadFile);
                        list.add(inputStream4);
                        formData.setFile4(flUploadFile);
                    }
                    else if(strFieldName.endsWith("5")) {
                        inputStream5 = new FileInputStream(flUploadFile);
                        list.add(inputStream5);
                        formData.setFile5(flUploadFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        mergePdf(list, formData);
        System.out.println("Finishing the main method");
        if(flUploadFile != null) {
            flUploadFile.delete();
        }
        strStatusMsg = "success";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        strStatusMsg = "failure";
    }
    return strStatusMsg;
}

private static void mergePdf(List<InputStream> list, FormDataBean formData) {
    OutputStream mergeOutputStream = null;
    Document document = null;
    try {
        mergeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Samik\\BCP\\" + formData.getStrFileName()));
        document = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, mergeOutputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
        for (InputStream tempInputStream : list) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
                pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);                 
            }

            tempInputStream.close();
            pdfReader.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Merging completed");
        deleteFiles(formData);
        pdfWriter.flush();
        pdfWriter.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
        try {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            if (mergeOutputStream != null) {
                mergeOutputStream.close();
            }
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Exiting the method");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void deleteFiles(FormDataBean formData) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    if(formData.getFile1()!=null) {
        formData.getFile1().delete();
    }
    if(formData.getFile2()!=null) {
        formData.getFile2().delete();
    }
    if(formData.getFile3()!=null) {
        formData.getFile3().delete();
    }
    if(formData.getFile4()!=null) {
        formData.getFile4().delete();
    }
    if(formData.getFile5()!=null) {
        formData.getFile5().delete();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the `IOException` for your changed code?

Comment: ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.flush(OutputStreamCounter.java:89)
 at com.itextpdf.text.DocWriter.close(DocWriter.java:233)
 at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(PdfWriter.java:1281)
 at com.tcs.pdfutil.MergePdfUtility.mergePdf(MergePdfUtility.java:150)

Comment: Ah, as you see in there, the new `IOException` is thrown in a completely different context.

Comment: But are you sure the exception stack trace occurred for the code you posted? The only time you explicitly call `PdfWriter.close` in `MergePdfUtility.mergePdf` is right after `pdfWriter.flush()`, and that `flush` call appears to not have caused an exception. Thus, there is no apparent cause for the underlying stream to already be closed in `PdfWriter.close`, either... And of course @Anonymity is correct, you should use a class from the `PdfCopy` family to merge PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, the `InputStream` has been closed before being passed into `mergePdf()` when the `BufferedInputStream` gets closed as below.

```
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
...
list.add(inputStream);
...
bin.close();
```

You can check the code of `java.io.BufferedInputStream#close`

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer;
    while ( (buffer = buf) != null) {
        if (bufUpdater.compareAndSet(this, buffer, null)) {
            InputStream input = in;
            in = null;
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
            return;
        }
        // Else retry in case a new buf was CASed in fill()
    }
}
```

PS: I suggest you to close the IO streams in finally block or use try-with-resources. For example:

```
private static void mergePdf(List<InputStream> list) {
    OutputStream mergeOutputStream = null;
    Document document = null;
    try{
        mergeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Samik\\BCP\\" + "Merger.pdf"));
        document = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, mergeOutputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
        for (InputStream tempInputStream : list) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
                pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    } catch (DocumentException|IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        try {
            if(mergeOutputStream != null) {
                mergeOutputStream.close();
            }
            if(document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}
```

or (ensure the Document has implemented java.io.Closeable):

```
private static void mergePdf(List<InputStream> list) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    try(OutputStream mergeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Samik\\BCP\\" + "Merger.pdf")); Document document = new Document()){
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, mergeOutputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.getDirectContent();
        for (InputStream tempInputStream : list) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                PdfImportedPage page = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
                pdfContentByte.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

updated on Jul 4th, 2018. A test method as per https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly.

```
public static void mergePdf(List<InputStream> inputStreams, String destinationFile) {
    try (OutputStream mergeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationFile))) {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, mergeOutputStream);
        document.open();
        for (InputStream tempInputStream : inputStreams) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
            copy.addDocument(pdfReader);
            System.out.println("Merging completed");
            pdfReader.close();
            tempInputStream.close();
        }
        document.close();
        copy.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

updated on Jul 5th, 2018
I don't know what framework you are using. But I have merged two pdfs successfully with Springboot 2.0.1.RELEASE. Here is my test codes

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/mergePdf.json", method = POST)
public void mergePdf(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
    mergePdfViaIText(Arrays.stream(files).map(file -> {
        try {
            LOG.debug(file.getOriginalFilename());
            return file.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()), "D:/result.pdf");
}

public static void mergePdfViaIText(List<InputStream> inputStreams, String destinationPath) {
    try (OutputStream mergeOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destinationPath))) {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, mergeOutputStream);
        document.open();
        for (InputStream tempInputStream : inputStreams) {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempInputStream);
            copy.addDocument(pdfReader);
            LOG.info("Merging completed");
            pdfReader.close();
            tempInputStream.close();
        }
        document.close();
        copy.close();
    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anonymity for your explanation. It helped me a lot - the work is done, but I am still facing the same issue, although partially. The modified code is updated in the main post above. Can you help me one more time understanding the issue?

Comment: @user3358385 First of all, please always close IO stream in finally block if you need to do that. As I see, you are parsing files from http request. If `item.isFormField()` is not true you will merge 5 files into 1 file and remove those 5 files. I think there is no need to save them before merging since they will be deleted at last.

Comment: @user3358385 oh my bad. Sorry for having misled you in my last comment. It is nothing to do with the way how you close IO stream. You haven't used right approach to merge pdfs. `PdfSmartCopy` should be more suitable than `PdfWriter` here. Please refer to https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly or you can checked a test method which I've posted.

Comment: I am sure I am missing something, but still not sure exactly what am I missing. I checked your link, from there I went to itextpdf example page. Lot of examples are listed down there, except an example of merging two PDFs - as simple as that. I used PdfCopy and PdfSmartCopy instead of PdfWriter, but I am having the same problem.

Comment: The requirement is, there is an UI screen, user can upload upto 5 PDF files, and when user clicks on a button, it will merge those 5 (2 are mandatory to merge, rest 3 are optional) PDFs in a single file. When I hard code the file names with their locations, they just work perfectly fine, but not when I select them dynamically.

Comment: and yes, lot of related discussions are there in this forum, none of them are being helpful to solve my issue.

Comment: @user3358385 at least you've merged local files successfully. It is great improvement. And you are still running into the same exception? If not please post the latest stack trace.

Comment: @user3358385 I've posted a new example base on springboot. Hope it will help.